# List are given in map<key,values> as values,how can I find one or more key which have largest list size java

Tags: java, performance, dictionary, iteration

I have written a method which returns a map.
The structure of the map is:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map;
```

The map can contain more than 1000 keys, and each key can contain a list more than 10000 in size.
I want to get those keys which have largest list size. Is there any approach to get the result in minimum time if possible?

Comment: You want to get the one key which points to the largest list?

Comment: What hinders you to iterate over the map and call the .size() method of the list? Just compare these and you're done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the performance is a priority, forget the [java-streams](/questions/tagged/java-streams) and use the native approach using a simple `for-loop` iteration.

```
String maxKey;
int maxSize = -1;

for (Entry<String, List<String>> list: map.entrySet()) {
    int size = list.getValue().size();
    if (size  > maxSize) {
        maxKey = list.getKey();
        maxSize = size;
    }
}
```

In case you want to store all the keys with the maximum, store them to the `Set<String>` and replace the condition with:

```
int size = list.getValue().size();
if (size  == maxSize) {
    maxKeySet.add(list.getKey());
}
if (size  > maxSize) {
    maxKeySet.clear();
    maxKeySet.add(list.getKey());
    maxSize = size;
}
```

Comment: If performance is priority, then one should rather use a different data structure ,-) ... nonetheless, you got my vote, as I you took the time to write down some code.

Comment: Note that OP asked for **all the keys** whose matching list is of the largest size. There may be more than one key with a list of size, say, 15,000.

Comment: @GhostCat: A good point! I expect the data are already mapped to the `Map <String, List<String>>` structure so I worked with it. Of course the source of the data matters.

Answer (score 3):

Using streams, you could put together a solution that iterates all entries of your map, fetches the **size** of each list, to finally provide that key that has the "max" size list. Or you follow the advice in the answer by Nikolas and implement that "old school" approach.

The problem with that: if you need to do that very often, it could still turn into a performance issue. From that point of view, you should ask yourself whether this "layout" of your data is really what your need.

Meaning: instead of using a Map, you could use a TreeMap and give that a special comparator. Which then **sorts** your map entries based on the length of these lists. Then you just pick the "first" entry, and you got your winner. The downside here is that the comparator only works on the keys going into the map, so you would probably need some special "wrapper class" where the key knows about the list size. Which is ugly.

Alternatively, you could create a special "wrapping map", that internally contains **two** maps:

- a `TreeMap<Integer, String>` that maps list sizes to your "real" map keys
- that real `Map<String, List<String>>` that holds your actual data.

Comment: "Which then sorts your map entries based on the length of these lists" TreeMap comparators sort the keys, not the entries or values.

Answer (score 0):

Using java8 streams filter feature:

```
Map <String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

Map <String, List<String>> filteredMap = map.entrySet().stream()
                    .filter(stringListEntry -> stringListEntry.getValue().size() > 100)
                    .limit(10)
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

`

Comment: I don't think the OP asked for a map of ten entries which have a size greater than 100. The OP asked for all the keys whose matching value has the largest size.

Comment: It is close enough, you can work with the above to achieve what you need. You can replace 100 with maxSize which can be easily computed in a similar way, you can replace limit with fintFirst as well.

Comment: In that way you would be going through it twice. Not very good, performance wise.

Comment: Most of the time you should think about readability first and don't worry about performance if there is no issue with it

Answer (score 0):

Group the entries by size of the value list, in a data structure that helps you find the largest key:

```
TreeMap<Integer, List<Entry<String, List<String>>>> collect =
    map.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(e -> e.getValue().size(), TreeMap::new, toList()));
```

(You can get just the keys using `mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, toList())` instead of `toList()`).

Then get the entries with the largest size using:

```
List<Map.Entry<String, List<String>>> largestEntries =
    grouped.lastEntry().getValue();
```

Of course, you can do this without streams too, and without keeping all the entries that are smaller than the largest:

```
List<Map.Entry<String, List<String>>> largestEntries = new ArrayList<>();
// Don't need both this and largestEntries;
// just adding to show how you'd only get keys.
List<String> largestKeys = new ArrayList<>();  
int largestSize = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
  if (entry.getValue().size() > largestSize) {
    largestEntries.clear();
    largestEntries.add(entry);
    largestKeys.add(entry.getKey());
    largestSize = entry.getValue().size();
  } else if (entry.getValue().size() == largestSize) {
    largestEntries.add(entry);
    largestKeys.add(entry.getKey());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You still can do it using `java-steam` API:

```
  Map<String, List<Integer>> map = Map.of(
                                        "a",List.of(1,2),
                                        "b",List.of(3,4,5,6),
                                        "c",List.of(7,8,9)
                                   );
```

An entry with maximum list size:

```
Optional<Map.Entry<String, List<Integer>>> max = map.entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    .max(Comparator.comparingInt(value -> value.getValue().size()));
```

a map with with entries with maximum list size:

```
Integer maxSize = max.get().getValue().size();
Map<String, List<Integer>> maxMap = map
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().size() == maxSize)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,Map.Entry::getValue));
```

or finally you can sortMap and store result in LinkedHashMap:

```
LinkedHashMap<String, List<Integer>> sortedMap = map
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(value -> value.getValue().size()))
        .collect(
                Collectors.toMap(
                        Map.Entry::getKey,
                        Map.Entry::getValue,
                        (u, v) -> {
                            throw new IllegalStateException(String.format("Duplicate key %s", u));
                        }, 
                        LinkedHashMap::new 
                )
        );
```